# Postman test to check the number of decimal places

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

I would like to test that the number of decimal places returned by a field in the response is equal to 5. Not sure if using regex is the best solution but this is what I have so far which does not seem to work:

```
pm.test("Check number of decimal place of my_variable field"), () => {
    _.each(jsonData, (results) => {
        if results.my_variable !== null){
            pm.expect(results.my_variable).to.match(/\d{1}.\d{5}/);
        }
    })
}
```

Below is a sample response. Note that the test passes even if it does not match the regex

```
 {
     "my_variable": "0.0198970000000000",

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an example of the response body to the question?

Comment: I have updated the description to add a sample response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things concerning your regex:

You need to escape the `.` with a `\`, otherwise the `.` will be interpreted as "any single character".

`\d{5}` is matching for 5 digits, but doesn't care if there are more digits following, thus you need to add `$` which checks if the end of line is reached, if nothing more is following the 5 digits.

This regex is working: `\d{1}\.\d{5}$`